# Message parsing from MQTT server

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, mqtt

I'm making a NodeMCU based home automation. I adapted code I found on internet for controlling a device (say LED) via MQTT broker hosted on a Raspberry Pi. It works fine. But when I try to scale it up for more than one device, I'm hitting a wall.

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  
  const char* t_bedroom_light1 = "/home/bedroom/light1";
  
  Serial.print("Topic from MQTT broker is : ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  char p = payload[0];

  // if MQTT comes a 0 turn OFF pin D4
  if (topic == "/home/bedroom/light1" && p == '0')
  {
    digitalWrite(LIGHT_PIN, LOW);
    Serial.println(" Turn Light Off! ");
  }

  // if MQTT comes a 1, turn ON pin D4
  if (topic == "/home/bedroom/light1" && p == '1')
  {
    digitalWrite(LIGHT_PIN, HIGH);
    Serial.println(" Turn Light On! " );
  }
}
```

Serial monitor receives and prints the topic correctly from MQTT server. But `topic == "/home/bedroom/light1"` never returns true. If I delete that part then `p =='0'` or `p=='1'` works fine by itself. I've tried comparing the topic with the locally declared char array, tried converting it into String and doing strcmp. Nothing. What am I doing wrong? Here is the Serial monitor output

```
12:43:20.346 -> .......
12:43:24.187 -> WiFi connected
12:43:24.187 -> IP address: 
12:43:24.187 -> 192.168.1.5
12:43:24.187 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
12:43:30.752 -> Topic from MQTT broker is : /home/bedroom/light1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you compare C strings.

When you write

```
if (topic == "/home/bedroom/light1")
```

you're comparing whether the character pointer `topic` is the same value as the address of the string `"/home/bedroom/light1"`, which of course it is not in this case.

To compare C strings, use the `strcmp()` function, which returns 0 if they're identical.

```
if (strcmp(topic, "/home/bedroom/light1") == 0 && p == '0')
```

Comment: Ty, that worked! The noob in me didn't know char arrays were Strings. I had actually tried casting the char array to a new String and used strcmp on that but for some reasons that didn't work.

Comment: Actually, char arrays are not `Strings` (note the capital S), but c-strings, [which is a significant difference](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=559153.0). `Strings` shouldonly not be used in devices, with limited memory (or only verys sparingly) while c-strings (char arrays) do not exhibit the same problems.

Comment: What @StarCat said. Unfortunately C strings also let you shoot yourself in the foot very easily. It's definitely one of the less intuitive parts of C unless you're coming to C from assembly language programming :)